# Why is this a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a trouble. I hope someone can do it.

> How to prove that
>   $\left\{a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{6} \mid (a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{Q}^4\right\}$ is a field?

I can't prove the existence of multiplicative inverse.
Thanks.

Comment: Which of the field axioms are giving you trouble? Have you tried doing this where you just add $\sqrt{2}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What related examples were done in class / your textbook before this?

Answer (score 2):

Hint (for proving the existence of multiplicative inverses):

If $z$ is a non-zero element of this form, show that so are $z^2,z^3$ and $z^4$.
The set $\{1,z,z^2,z^3,z^4\}$ is linearly dependent over $\Bbb{Q}$. Why? So you get a non-trivial linear relation between them. How can you take advantage?

---

Try to mimic the following proof for the fact that multiplicative inverses of numbers of the form $z=a+b\sqrt3\neq0$ are of the same form.

We easily see that $z^2=(a^2+3b^2)+2ac\sqrt3$ is of the same form. So is $1=z^0$.
Let $a_0,a_1,a_2$ be unknowns. Consider the equation
$$
a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2=0. \qquad(*)
$$
By looking at the coefficients of $1$ and $\sqrt3$ we see that if $a_0,a_1,a_2)$ is a solution of the
linear system of equations
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cccccc}
a_0&+&aa_1&+&(a^2+3b^2)a_2&=&0,\\
&&ba_1&+&(2ac)a_2&=&0,
\end{array}\right.
$$
then equation $(*)$ also holds.
Two linear homogeneous equations, three unknowns, so linear algebra tells us that there is a non-trivial solution $(a_0,a_1,a_2)\in\Bbb{Q}^3$. As $1,z,z^2$ are all non-zero, at least two of the $a_i$:s must be non-zero. If $a_0\neq0$, then
$$
a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2=0\implies \frac1z=-\frac{a_1}{a_0}-\frac{a_2}{a_0}z
$$
simply by dividing the equation by $a_0z\neq0.$ But here the the right hand side
is clearly of the form $a+b\sqrt3$, so in our set (soon to be shown a field).
If $a_0=0$, then $a_1\neq0\neq a_2$, and we divide the equation $(a_0+)a_1z+a_2z^2=0$ by $a_1z^2$ instead.

This time you will get four equations and five unknowns. The exact form of the powers $z^2,z^3,z^4$ will not matter as long as you convince yourself of the fact that you get something like
$$
z^j=a_j+b_j\sqrt2+c_j\sqrt3+d_j\sqrt6
$$
for all $j=1,2,3,4$ and some rational numbers $a_j,b_j,c_j,d_j$.

Comment: I can't prove the existence of multiplicative inverse.

Comment: I elaborated a bit by showing how you can do the same in the field $\{a+b\sqrt3\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}$. You will get a larger system with more unknowns. Can you manage? There are also other methods for showing that this is a field, but this is one of the more down-to-earth ones I think?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is a field by definition. Prove
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4
$$

and show 
$$
\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\}
$$

form a basis for the extension.